# What is the correct term for "race conditions" in single-threaded environments like JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

To start with, I'm *not* asking for another "does JavaScript have race conditions" discussion.

My problem: In JavaScript, it is possible for two non-sequential functions to access the same variable. Example:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 0;

setTimeout(
  function() { a = 5; },
  Math.random() * 1000
);

setTimeout(
  function() { b = a; },
  Math.random() * 1000
);

setTimeout(
  function() { console.log(b); },
  2000
);
```

Now, many people insist that this is not a race condition because the operations are atomic. At the same time, I have yet to find somebody who explains what this type of error/situation *is* called, except for one colleague who calls it something like "a timing based variable handling error" (which is rather long to include in conversation, especially if you have to say it dozens of times to explain something).

This is especially frustrating because, whenever I start explaining a problem with "it's a race condition", I immediately get interrupted with an unhelpful "there are no race conditions in JavaScript".

Could somebody tell me what the "correct" term is, if there is one?

**Edit:** Yes, the example is highly simplified. The real case includes HTTP requests, promises and AngularJS render cycles interfering in ways that I don't even understand well enough to include them as an example here. The random timeouts are there to *simulate* what happens. Once again, discussion on code quality really doesn't help me solve the communication problem.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, there's nothing going on here besides assignments at random times

Comment: They are wrong.  Race condition isn't explicit to a threaded environment.

Comment: From wikipedia: "A race condition or race hazard is the behavior of an electronics, software, or other system where the output is dependent on the sequence or timing of other uncontrollable events. It becomes a bug when events do not happen in the order the programmer intended."

Comment: The question is what order do you intend these to happen in and is this a bug? This all feels very artificial TBH. Can you have race conditions in Js, yes.

Comment: The provided example is contrived. If you've had these discussions with colleagues before, provide a real-world example and then someone may be able to tell you what it would be called.

Comment: Technically, because no resource would ever be accessed by two threads concurrently because JavaScript is single threaded and all actions are atomic, you cannot have race conditions. However, if you skew the definition of race conditions to include cases of things just happening in the unintended order, I suppose you could. I wouldn't call those valid race conditions though, I would simply call it bad and silly programming practice.

Comment: Of course it's artificial, @Liam - it's a simplified example. In my case, it's most often the interaction between changing variables and the AngularJS render cycles, but putting that as an example here would result in an unnecessarily long example. Either way, I'm not asking how to solve the problem, just for the correct way to describe it so I don't get interrupted in mid-sentence.

Comment: Sounds like a `logic flaw`..  bit shorter than `a timing based variable handling error`.. anyway.. :)

Comment: Hmm...a race condition is generally when two threads are accessing the same resource at the same time and modify it. But this code is single-threaded. I would think the timeouts will be added to the event stack in the same order every time, and executed one at a time. Of course there is async programming in JavaScript (just not the example above)...so, per your example of Angular rendering,  maybe Angular uses Promises or something rather than timeouts, which would make the behaviour a lot less predictable (although still semantically whether it's a race condition is debatable).

Comment: Ultimately, I would say this is just a timing based variable handling error, and sometimes you just can't explain poor programming practices any better than with a long winded phrase like that.

Comment: I'd agree it sounds more like a logical flaw. If Promises are involved, then you can solve the problem by attaching callbacks which run when they're resolved (or rejected) and thus ensure code runs in the desired order.

Comment: Have none of the commenters had a situation where the user and the server might update the same data independently?  This clearly can happen, in, say, a shared editing environment.  Knowing how to clearly describe the problem can help in discussing it, and sometimes in solving it.  That said, although I think this is a race condition in the broadest sense, using that term for it can just lead to debate.  But I don't have a better one at the moment.

Comment: Setting a random timeout is undeterministic behaviour :)

Comment: @JonasW: yes it is, but the OP made clear that this is just an example to show that the condition could occur, not actual code, and then followed that up with an explanatory comment mentioning the Angular render cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is correct.

It is not the race of the processes or threads, its race of task completion. Actually, you can do the same in multithreaded environment where it is not about which thread reach the same code first, but which task is completed first.

Even famous libraries like Bluebird or Async call this functions as .race()

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.race.html

https://caolan.github.io/async/race.js.html

---

In other words - if these two guys call it race, I think you can either: https://github.com/caolan https://github.com/petkaantonov